# Update Oracle Database table through Email

Tags: database, oracle, email, oracle11g, dblink

I need to setup a email to database table link. So basically, the user will get an email with 2 options, Yes or No, the user should be able to click on either option and the database table with data example like "Did the user click yes or no" will get updated with either yes or no. I have some experience with SQL and Oracle but not with email links like this. An example I have seen for this would be something like a manager gets an approval request email for employee and the manager either clicks approve or reject in the email and the request gets approved or rejected as per the manager's response. Can someone please tell me what I would need to set up a system like that?

Comment: You may want to look into Oracle REST data services (ORDS). It is one option, where you could code a package/procedure that makes the data changes, like an API; then you publish that procedure call through ORDS and include the URL in your e-mail.